# Link to image database

Tags: asp.net, razor, webmatrix

I have the following page:

```
@{
    if (Request["ID"].IsInt())
    {
        var imgID = Request["ID"].AsInt();

        //Data
        var db = Database.Open("AMSDArquiteturaConnectionString");
        var image = db.QuerySingle("select * from Images where [ID] = @0", imgID);

        if (image.MimeType.StartsWith("image"))
        {
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "inline; filename=" + image.Name);
        }
        else
        {
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + image.Name);
        }

        Response.BinaryWrite((byte[])image.File);

    }
}
```

I'm using a plugin to image to zoom in, and I need to make the link point to an image.

```
<a rel="images" title="MyImage" href="ProjectImage?ID=@img.ID"></a>
```

the problem is that when I click on the link I see only a meaningless code.

How to make this link point to a picture that is in the database?

Comment: Can you include the "meaningless code" in your question? Is it an error message or just random characters?

Answer (score 1):

You need to establish whether the problem is with how you are using the plugin, or your Razor code. Request the page directly, hard coding a value for `imgID` to make sure it works properly. If you have based your database table and code on an [article from a bloke called Mikesdotnetting](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/148/Save-And-Retrieve-Files-From-a-Sql-Server-CE-Database-with-WebMatrix), you can simplify it a bit by using the `WebImage` helper:

```
@{
    WebImage image = null;
    int id = Request["Id"].AsInt();
    var db = Database.Open("FileUploading");
    var sql = "Select * From Files Where FileId = @0";
    var file = db.QuerySingle(sql, id);
    if(file != null){
        image = new WebImage((byte[])file.FileContent);
    }
}   
@if(image != null){
    @image.Write(image.ImageFormat)
}
```

If that works, then the plugin might the problem. Try requesting the image from an `img` tag, with the `src` pointing to the page that generates the image. It's an odd approach that uses anchors to display images instead of `img` tags.

Or it could be the image itself. [Only some image types are supported by browsers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_web_browsers#Image_format_support).

Answer (score 0):

You might need to specify the mime type. Something like this:

```
Response.ContentType = image.MimeType
```

The "meaningless code" is probably the image, the browser just doesn't know that the data represents an image and is showing it in raw format. This code should tell it what it needs to know.

Comment: I did that too .. and the same thing.

Placed above the line:
Response.BinaryWrite ((byte []) image.File);

Comment: Another problem is the SELECT *. You probably want to specify a single field to make sure you get the right one.

Comment: OK, I agree. I will address this later. But how to solve the current problem?

Comment: That might BE your problem if the first field returned by the query is the wrong one.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you doing this in a razor page? It should be an Action method in your controller. Something like this.

```
public ActionResult Image(int? id) {
    if (id.HasValue) {
        //Data
        var db = Database.Open("AMSDArquiteturaConnectionString");
        var Image = db.QuerySingle("select * from Images where [ID] = @0", id.Value);


        FileContentResult result = new FileContentResult((byte[])Image.File, Image.MimeType);

        if (Image.MimeType.StartsWith("image")) {
            result.FileDownloadName = Image.Name;
        }
        return result;

    } else {
        return new HttpNotFoundResult();
    }
}
```

My guess would be that view engine doesn't like it when you use it that way.

Comment: This question is tagged WebMatrix. There are no Controllers or Actions in ASP.NET Web Pages.